# How to pass arguments to a python gdb script launched from command line

Tags: python, gdb, gdb-python

I'd like to pass some command line arguments to a python script run via `gdb` command, but importing the gdb module in python removes the argv attribute from sys. How do I access arg1 and arg2 within my python script shown in my example?

#### Command line execution:

```
$ gdb -x a.py --args python -arg1 -arg2
```

#### a.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gdb
import sys
print('The args are: {0}'.format(sys.argv))
gdb.execute('quit')
```

#### Error raised:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'
```

#### Versions:

- GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2
- Python 2.6.6

#### Edit:

The end target I'll be debugging is a C executable that is already running, so I'll be attaching to it later in the script, so `gdb -x a.py --args python -arg1 -arg2` is not correct either since the `python` part prints a gdb error: `Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python...(no debugging symbols found)...done.`...

Comment: You might find something helpful in https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html or its equivalent in 2 if you're using that.

Comment: @AdamBorgo argparse was added in Python version 2.7 and I'm using 2.6, however I had tried using optparse originally but it relies on sys.argv. So I boiled all that down to this simplified question actually. Thanks for your suggestion though (maybe argparse it *would* work, just not in this application)!

Comment: This isn't exactly what you want, but: If you can make `a.py` define a python function, say `a`, then you can give gdb an argument such as `-ex "python a('the answer is ',42)"`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick your answer is the closest I've come to a solution. What I don't like is its kludginess, I was hoping there would be a more straightforward method. This does work, and thank you, but maybe the answer is it cannot be done? `$ gdb -ex "python import os,sys; sys.path.append(os.getcwd()); from a import *; main('arg1', 'arg2')"`. My best idea is to write a helper bash script that launches a.py (what I'm already doing), but redirects the command line arguments to a temp file that the a.py script reads from <- this is less kludgy especially with tricky arguments and can use optparse..

Answer (score 9):

**`-ex py`**

This is a possibility:

argv.py

```
print(arg0)
print(arg1)
```

Invocation:

```
gdb --batch -ex 'py arg0 = 12;arg1 = 3.4' -x argv.py
```

or equivalently:

```
gdb --batch -ex 'py arg0 = 12' -ex 'py arg1 = 3.4' -x argv.py
```

Output:

```
12
3.4
```

Then you could wrap that in the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

doc="
Pass parameters to python script.

Usage:

  $0 scrpit.py 1 2

Where scrpit.py uses the arguments like:

  print(arg0)
  print(arg1)
"

py="$1"
shift
cli=''
i=0
for arg in $*; do
  cli="$cli -ex 'py arg$i = $arg'"
  i=$(($i+1))
done
eval gdb --batch $cli -x "$py"
```

Tested on Python 3.8.6, GDB 9.2, Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: You can use `-ex 'py arg0=arg0; arg1=arg1; ...'` declaration/assignment instead of dividing them into several individual statements starting with `-ex 'py'`.

Comment: @XinyiLi thanks, added to answer. Abrupt toad worship is great!!!

Answer (score 3):

It's not totally clear to me what you are trying to do.

An invocation of the form:

```
gdb --args something arg arg
```

Tells gdb to use `something` as the program to be debugged, with `arg arg` as the initial command-line arguments for the `run` command.  You can inspect these inside gdb with `show args`.

So, your command is saying "I want to debug the `python` executable, passing it some arguments".

However, later you say you plan to `attach` to some already-running executable.

So, I think you're probably trying to script gdb in Python -- not debug the `python` executable.

The good news is, this is possible, just not the way you've written it.  Instead you have a couple choices:

- Make a `.py` file holding your script and tell gdb to `source` it, e.g., with `gdb -x myscript.py` (which you've already done...)
- Use `-ex` to invoke some Python explicitly, like `-ex 'python print 23'`.

Comment: Your first suggestion is what I would like to accomplish: `$ gdb -x a.py`, but I need to send command line arguments TO this a.py script. The a.py script eventually attaches to a C program running in the background (unimportant). I don't want to just start gdb `$ gdb` then use the `r` command later which is what using `args` seems to assume because it needs the program name `something` as its initial argument.

Comment: Write a wrapper script that takes your arguments, generates a Python file, and then invokes gdb appropriately.