# How to pass variables to sys.args? (python gdb script)

Tags: python, gdb, gdb-python

I want to pass command line arguments to sys.args (to a gdb python script). I saw this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31227632/6307086) but would like pass arbitrary number of arguments.
Like:

```
gdb --batch -x myScript.py 2 3 4 12 23 ..
```

myScript.py:

```
import gdb
import sys

print(sys.argv[1:])
```

Is is possible?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: It should work, but beware there are limits to the number of command-line arguments that can be passed, and those limits are implementation (including OS) dependant.

Comment: I did try. Unfortunately, I get an error saying "excess command line arguments ignored".

Comment: With `gdb` you specify the argument list to the `run` command.  The `-x` statement is followed by a file containing `gdb` commands, not a python script.